# sonar null pointer exception in java piece of code

Tags: java

I have a below piece of code in which sonar lint is showing the exception A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "mainDTO" is nullable here.

Please advise how can I correct the same

```
public mainDTO create(mainDTO mainDTO) throws NotFoundException {
        if (mainDTO != null) {
            Main main = mainMapper.tomain(mainDTO);
            mainRepository.save(main);
            return mainMapper.tomainDTO(main);
        }
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Can not create the main " + mainDTO.getMainId()); // ** Sonar Qube exception
    }
```

Comment: Check your code: you call a method on `null` (after null check) object ` mainDTO.getMainId()`

Comment: The only way that your `throw` statement can be reached is if `mainDTO` fails the null check on the first line of the method. If that happens then `mainDTO.getMainId()` is going to blow up with your NPE.

Answer (score 0):

By writing the line:

```
if (mainDTO != null) {
```

you're flagging that it is possible for `mainDTO` to be null. But you haven't done a null check around

```
mainDTO.getMainId()
```

where Sonar complains. If `mainDTO` is indeed null, then a null pointer exception will be thrown at this line.